# Linq Count item from multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables below and I want to count the number of Book with category by CategoryCode

| ID | bookName | CategoryCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ULYSSES | B1 |
| 2 | Dye Yielding Plants | B3 |
| 3 | Sapiens | B2 |
| 4 | LOLITA | B1 |

| CategoryCode | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | Novel Book |
| B2 | knowledge Book |
| B3 | General Book |

And I want the result to be:

| CategoryCode | CategoryName | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | Novel Book | 2 |
| B2 | Knowledge Book | 1 |
| B3 | General book | 1 |

This is my code

```
var CountItem = (from p in context.Product
                        join c in context.Category on p.CategoryCode equals c.CategoryCode
                    group p by p.CategoryCode 
                    into g 
                    select new {
                        Key = g.Key, Count = g.Select(x => x.CategoryCode).Distinct().Count() 
                    }).ToList();
```

Looks like i went in the wrong direction. Please help me

Comment: Why not simply: `Category.Select(c => new{ c.CategoryCode, c.CategoryName, Count=Product.Count(p => p.CategoryCode==c.CategoryCode) })`? If you just want those categories where products are available add `.Where(c => Product.Any(p => p.CategoryCode==c.CategoryCode))`

Comment: i think you could use `group new {p.CategoryCode, c.CategoryName} by p.CategoryCode` and `select new {key = g.key, count = g.Count(), code = g.First().CategoryName}`

Comment: I understand.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you use distinct, but if you want just count of every book in category this request should work

```
from p in books
group p by p.CategoryCode
into g
join c in categories on g.Key equals c.CategoryCode
select new
{
   CategoryCode = g.Key,
   CategoryName = c.Name,
   ItemCount = g.Count()
};
```